# Solve boundary value problem $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I would like to solve the boundary value problem $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = f(x)$ with initial conditions $$y(-1)=y(1)=0$$
My thoughts were to try to find the solution without the conditions, and then filling in this solution in the differential equation to find all the right constants. However, I'm stuck.

I thought the following:
$$y(x) = A + Bx + \int_{x_0}^x \left(\int_{x_0}^\eta f(\xi)d\xi \right)d\eta$$

But how can I proceed?

Comment: Simply plug the initial conditions to get the values of $A$ and$B$.

Comment: If you have power series representation of $f(x)$ then yes A and B like that should do nicely because there will be nothing left from $f$ for those coefficients in the power series.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Yes I know I'm supposed to, but I don't know how to plug this in in the double integral

Comment: Replace $x$ by its value.

Comment: $$A=-\frac{(F(-1)+F(1))}{2}$$
$$B=F(1)-A=F(1)+\frac{(F(-1)+F(1))}{2}=F(1)+\frac{F(-1)}{2}$$ With $F(x)=\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\Big(\int_{x_{0}}^{\nu}f(\xi)d\xi\Big)d\nu$

Comment: @KirylPesotski But shouldn't I fill something in for $x_0$?